# Show checkbox checked in reactive form load in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to show my checkbox checked when my form loads.
In my Html page:-

```
<div>
    Is Active
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="IsActive" [ngModel]="isactivechk">
</div>
```

Code In my .ts page

```
export class UserregistrationComponent {
isactivechk:boolean=true;
}
```

**This is a child control using it in a parent controller. I want to check the checkbox on Parent page load**

Comment: I tried, but still it is unchecked, but as soon as I write something in the form, only then it gets checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your checkbox is part of a child component and you want to pre-check it from the parent component, you'll need to make sure you're passing the initial value correctly and managing the form control from the parent component. Here's how you can approach this
Let's say you have a parent component (parent.component.ts) and a child component (child.component.ts). In the child component's template (child.component.html), you'll define the checkbox like this.

```
<!-- child.component.html -->
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="myCheckboxControl"> My Checkbox
</label>
```

In the child component's TypeScript file (child.component.ts), define an Input property to receive the form control from the parent.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() myCheckboxControl: FormControl;
}
```

In the parent component's template (parent.component.html), use the child component and pass the form control to it.

```
<!-- parent.component.html -->
<app-child [myCheckboxControl]="myForm.get('myCheckbox')"></app-child>
```

In the parent component's TypeScript file (parent.component.ts), you'll define the form and its initial value:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      myCheckbox: [true] // Set the initial value here (true for checked, false for unchecked)
    });
  }
}
```

By passing the form control to the child component as an @Input() property, you ensure that the form control is shared between the parent and the child components. This way, when the form initializes in the parent component, the checkbox in the child component should be pre-checked accordingly.

Comment: Why do pass the formControl as Input to the children instead of use viewProviders?

Comment: By passing the form control to the child component as an @Input() property, you ensure that the form control is shared between the parent and the child components. This way, when the form initializes in the parent component, the checkbox in the child component should be pre-checked accordingly.

Comment: if you use viewprovider too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Angular Reactive Forms and want to pre-check a checkbox when the form loads, you can follow these steps:

**Import Required Modules:** Make sure you've imported the necessary modules in your component file (e.g., **your-component.ts**)

```
 this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  // Other form controls...
  myCheckbox: [true] // Set initial value to true for a pre-checked checkbox
});
```

**Bind the Checkbox in the Template:**
In your component's template file (e.g., yo**ur-component.component.html**), bind the checkbox control to the form group using the **formControlName** directive

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<!-- Other form controls... -->
 <input type="checkbox" formControlName="myCheckbox"> Check me
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried, it gets checked automatically only when I type something in the form

Comment: try this -- >   import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef)                    ngOnInit() {
  this.cd.detectChanges(); // Manually trigger change detection
}

Comment: thanks, but still the same result. I think since it is a child component, that's why on load it is not getting checked. In parent component I need to access it

Comment: okay, I understand that. need to check your all code

Answer (score 0):

You can set value using formBuilder

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      IsActive: new FormControl(true) // Set initial value here
    });
  }
```

Comment: Still the same, no change

Comment: can you share the environment in stackblitz?